# How to add microsfot bot to teams group programatically?

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams, mbf

I'm trying to add Microsoft bot to teams group through an api,i have gone through graph api documentation and teams apps concepts etc, but i didn't find anything, main goal of the this idea is to add bot with out user interaction.

Is there any way to add bot?

Answer (score 0):

It's currently in beta version you can try to use

```
POST /teams/{team-id}/installedApps
{
  teamsApp: <AppId>
}
```

This API currently require admin consent so don't know if I recommend it [more here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsappinstallation-add?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http),
I saw apps like Polly that are doing it in an undocumented way, no idea how